# VSTS and LocalDB: Failed to update database XXX because the database is read-only

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, integration-testing, localdb

We're using VSTS and we've started getting an error during the integration tests run during the continuous build process. We're using localdb in order to run the tests agains a predefined mdb file that is copied to the output folder of the unit test project.

We're using a powershell script to ensure that localdb is executing. IT has a single line:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "MSSQLLocalDB" -s
```

The connection string used for running the integration tests is built dynamically like this:

```
$"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename={Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath)}\\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

The only thing we've changed recently is that we've started building against .NET 4.7.1, but I think that shouldn't have any influence in these problems...

Any clues on why we've started getting these errors?

Comment: Do you update records in the test or the mdb file has been updated? Do you use private agent? Try to specify database name in the connection string(`Initial Catalog=xx`). On the other hand, try to execute `ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT`

Comment: I ran a CI just now and started facing the same issue. I have been running the same build for a v. long time and didn't change anything with the localdb database

Comment: That's really similar to what happened in my case: it was working for a long time and then it stopped. In my case, I've updated the framework version, but that shouldn't have any influence... I think...

Comment: What're steps to reproduce this issue? Can you share the log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug variable to true, then queue build) Do you update records in the test or the mdb file has been updated? Do you use private agent? Try to specify database name in the connection string(`Initial Catalog=xx`). On the other hand, try to execute `ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT`.

Comment: In my case, I'm using NH and the integration tests are using the PersistenceSpecification object (which, if I'm not mistaken, will insert and then load the data to see if everything is ok...)

Comment: What's the result if you don't insert records to database?

Comment: Well, the only tests that are failing are the integration tests that check my NH mappings... I don't use the db for anything else...

Comment: What do you mean NH mappings?

Comment: Hello again. Nh == NHibernate.

Comment: What's the detail code of integration tests?

Comment: Hello Chen. Sorry for the delay, but I was away. Can you be more precise? My code looks like this: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Persistence-specification-testing. Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: I have the same problem with an project. It is Building for a long time and in December a rebuild of previous successful build commit failed. I my case the error occur in the Initialize method of entity framework with a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: `Failed to update database "D:\A\1\S\<project>\<project>.TEST\BIN\RELEASE\<project>.MDF" because the database is read-only.`.

Comment: Yep, that's the same problem... Unfortunately, there's still no cause (or solution...)

Comment: Use the sqllocaldb nuget package, it solves all these issues https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb

Comment: Erik, can you be a little more specific?

Comment: The is a github Issue [Install SQL Local DB on Windows images](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/issues/34) on the vsts-image-generation project. Do not know if this maybe related.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the case. My powershell script is starting sqllocaldb 13 (checked on the logs) and the mdf file has already been updated to that version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to ensure that the .mdf you're restoring is located in the Build agent users temp directory.

The temp directory location can be retrieved using the %TEMP% environment variable. In c#

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")
```

You can restore using sp_attach_db

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'YourDbName', @filename1 = 'TEMPFOLDER\YourDbName.mdf'
```

Where TEMPFOLDER in the above line has been replace however you see fit to be the value of the TEMP environment variable.

Comment: Hello Grant. So, you're saying that I need to copy the mdb file into the temp folder (instead of the release folder) and attach it from there? Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to achieve that? I currently have a *shared project* with my MDF file and 2 test projects which reference the shared one. The MDF file is set as **Copy always** so it ends up in the *bin* directory of both my test projects. In both projects I have `"Data Source=(LocalDB)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf;...` so I directly use this connection string in my tests. I do not like the approach to have a pre/post-build script that copies my mdf to TEMP. Is there another way?